# Cannot load and overlay transparent image in OpenCV

Tags: c++, image, opencv, overlay, transparent

I have *transparentGUI.png* image with **transparent background** - in GIMP it looks like that:

[image]

When I load it in OpenCV by `Mat imgColorPanel = imread("transparentGUI.png", -1);` and then display it by `imshow("widok", imgColorPanel);`, i can see this image with white background (which is wrong, because **it should be transparent**):

[image]

Eventually I want to overlay this image (with it's transparent background) on camera captured image. If I do it using other image, which has background (so **it's not** transparent) - then it's correctly overlayed.

However, when I want to overlay transparentGUI.png image on captured camera image by `addWeighted(imgColorPanel, 0.8, imgOriginal, 0.6, 0, imgOriginal);`, program crashes with console error:

[image]

as well as Debugging error:

[image]

Everything works unless I want to load and display image with transparent background. I assume it may be a conflict with `imgOriginal`, because it's in HSV - I am building program for object detection by HSV colors, so i cannot change it. Is it ok with overlaing HSV image with BGRA image (the transparent one)? Default color range of OpenCV is BGR, so even camera capture image is converted to HSV, then I can overlay it by other image which is BGR - so, I think that something else must be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

imgColorPanel and imgOriginal should have the same size. From your statement, imgColorPanel has 4 channels (RGBA). To make "addWeighted" work, imgOriginal should also have 4 channels, instead of 3 HSV channels.

For "imshow", I think it is just display issue, and you may print out the size of imgColorPanel to check if it has 4 channels.

Comment: How to convert imgOriginal to have 4 channels then? I tried doing `cvtColor(imgOriginal, imgOriginal, COLOR_HSV2RGB_FULL);`, but it causes crash. There is no **COLOR_HSV2RGBA** option in `cvtColor()` function to convert it from one color space to another - what to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

You are having two different problems:

> i can see this image with white background (which is wrong, because it
>   should be transparent)

well, it's not *wrong* because you **can't see transparency** anyway and there's no standard consensus on how it should be rendered independent of context. In the case of GIMP you do see something - the background of the context-window containing the image. In the case of HighGui you probably get a white-background simply because that's the nominal background in this case. The only way around this is to tell the program what exactly *seeing transparency* means in the context of your program. This might require using another GUI-system, depends on what you want to do.

> program crashes with console error

as the error message says, the problem is that the images you are trying to overlay have a different size. A solution would be to first create a transparent base image of the desired size, e.g. like this:

```
cv::Mat imgColorPanel {imgOriginal.rows, imgOriginal.cols, CV_8UC4, cv::Scalar{0,0,0,0}};
```

and then load the panel from your image in the desired part of the base using a ROI (the image has to be smaller than the base of course..) e.g.:

```
cv::Mat panel {cv::imread("PATH/TO/FILE")};
cv::Rect roi {0,0,panel.rows,panel.cols}; // x,y,width,height
cv::Mat imRoi {imgColorPanel(roi)};
imRoi = panel.clone();
```

Comment: I need this image **imgColorPanel** as GUI (menu) to be transparent. Where should I use your proposal code - after loading image from disk? I mean, you said that it's faster than loading image from disk - but that GUI image is on the disk. So what that code will do? Should I load non transparent image and then use your code to fake it's transparency for OpenCV?

Comment: my code will simply create a BGRA all-transparent `cv::Mat` - I just noticed that your image is not fully-transparent, I'll edit my answer to add a solution for this.

Comment: I noticed (maybe obvious thing) that transparent image has 4 channels, where main image has only 3 channels. I checked it using `.channels()` function. So it also may be a problem. If it is, then how to convert main image (the one to be overlayed), to 4 channels?

Comment: to convert a 3-channel `cv::Mat` to a 4-channel one you could simply create a new 1-channel one (with the desired values for the 4th channel) and use `cv::merge` to merge the original with the channel you've created into a new `cv::Mat`. Documentation is here http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=merge#cv.Merge

Comment: There is still a crash with your code. When I convert main image from HSV to BGRA (from 3 channels to 4, so both of them have 4 channels), then I have weird colors in view: http://imgur.com/5DEUTKL

Comment: if the original is HSV then you need to convert it to BGR first, maybe with something like: `cv::cvtColor(hsvImg, bgrImg, CV_HSV2BGR);`

Comment: I converted it from HSV > BGR > BGRA - and this caused weird colors on screen I gave link to (on imgur.com).
However your code doesn't work - there is still crash.

Comment: not sure what causes the weird colours. As far as the crash is concerned, what code are you referring to exactly and what is the crash? is there any error message?

Comment: The error in console is http://imgur.com/gjoCs5y
I am referring to code in your post

Comment: it seems to me that you're trying to fit a ROI bigger than the original.. please double check that `panel` is smaller than `imgColorPanel`

Comment: I checked it in two ways - **1.** When I load **transparentGUI.png** (which is 640x480) and then trying to overlay it on camera image (640x480px as well). I got crash. **2.**  I clipped only "menu" part of gui and saved as "smallGUI.png" (size 640x60) and I got crash as well with Your code.
However I managed to overlay that smaller GUI image on camera image, but of course it's not transparent - so I still **can't overlay transparent image on camera image**, cause I got crash. No matter if image is smaller. Maybe Your code is wrong?